# Upload files to Backblaze B2 with SFTP or FTPS or SCP?

Tags: script, sftp, scp, backblaze

We have a Backblaze B2 business account, and from my understanding it should be possible to upload files using SFTP. Or alternatively FTPS or SCP would also be fine (I just want to be able to upload/backup files from a scripted process).

However I haven't been able to find the correct settings, such as which hostname to use or how/where to setup the appropriate credentials.

I understood this requires creating a 'bucket' in our Backblaze B2 account, but I don't know how to go from there.

I have a bucket, which includes a bucketid and endpoint (hostname), and a KeyID and Master Application Key. And of course our main Backblaze login details. Is it possible to do automated uploads using SFTP with these details, or do I need anything else?

Comment: I didn't find any reference for SFTP support on Backblaze B2. Why do you think it should be possible? And what do you need it for?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: Your own WinSCP can do it...

Comment: @harrymc But that's not SFTP :)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl When asking around for a cloud storage solution that supports SFTP, someone recommended Backblace B2. But maybe this advice was incorrect, can't tell for sure. I need it to automate some daily upload / backup processes on our of our server.

Answer (score 1):

Backblaze B2 Cloud Storage is totally compatible with the Amazon S3 API.

The Backblaze Help article
[Can WinSCP with B2?](https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047123254-Can-WinSCP-with-B2-)
recommends the following for using the free tool
[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

WinSCP can be configured with B2 Cloud Storage by following the steps below.

> 1. Start WinSCP and you are automatically taken to the connection manager page.
> 2. Click on New Site and then under File Protocol, select Amazon S3. Enter the S3 Endpoint URL, Key ID, and Application Key (App Keys) into
>    the appropriate fields.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems very promising! The only thing is I don't use WinSCP (I intend to use SCP in a bash script on a Linux server) so I'm a bit confused about the 'File protocol' option. Is that also available when using SCP from the command line?

Comment: Sorry, WinSCP is for Windows. SCP/SSH are not supported, so can't be used. For other options, see the post [How to scp to Amazon s3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328849/how-to-scp-to-amazon-s3) where the answer was negative, but other options were listed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a bash script, you could use the [B2 command-line tool](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/quick_command_line.html). For example:

```
export B2_APPLICATION_KEY_ID=<Your App Key ID>
export B2_APPLICATION_KEY=<Your App Key>

b2 upload-file <Your-Bucket-Name> </path/to/file> <filenameInB2>
```